# how to make login with only one field + cakephp 2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am trying to make a login by getting/authorizing only one input *user_number* (**Not** username - password).

I made my current login page with the following way:
[Cakephp2.x simple login](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)

Any help plz!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Keep it simple

If you only have one way of identifying users, the simplest (and therefore recommended) way to identify users would be to define your own login function. e.g.:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $number = $this->request->data['User']['user_number'];
        $user = $this->User->findByUserNumber($number);
        if ($user && $this->Auth->login($user)) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('User %d doesn\'t exist', $number), 'default', array(), 'auth');
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this varies very little from [the standard way of logging a user in](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in) with Cake 2.x

Answer (score 1):

### Create a Custom Authentication object

Create a Custom Authentication object that authenticates uses by user-number only;

[Creating Custom Authentication objects](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects)

app/Controller/Component/Auth/UserNumberAuthenticate.php

```
App::uses('BaseAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class UserNumberAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate {
    public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response) {
        $userModel = $this->settings['userModel'];
        list($plugin, $model) = pluginSplit($userModel);
        
        $fields = $this->settings['fields'];
        if (
            empty($request->data[$model])
            || empty($request->data[$model][$fields['username']])
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->_findUser($request->data[$model][$fields['username']]);
    }

    /**
     * Find a user record via his user-number/identifier
     *
     * @param string $usernumber The user-number/identifier.
     
     * @return Mixed Either false on failure, or an array of user data.
     */
    protected function _findUser($usernumber) {
        $userModel = $this->settings['userModel'];
        list($plugin, $model) = pluginSplit($userModel);
        $fields = $this->settings['fields'];
        
        $conditions = array(
            $model . '.' . $fields['username'] => $usernumber,
        );
        if (!empty($this->settings['scope'])) {
            $conditions = array_merge($conditions, $this->settings['scope']);
        }
        $result = ClassRegistry::init($userModel)->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'recursive' => $this->settings['recursive'],
            'contain' => $this->settings['contain'],
        ));
        if (empty($result) || empty($result[$model])) {
            return false;
        }
        $user = $result[$model];
        unset($result[$model]);
        return array_merge($user, $result);
    }
}
```

Then specify that you want to use your custom authentication object

Inside your AppController:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'UserNumber' => array(
                'userModel' => 'User',
                'fields'    => array('username' => 'user_number')
            )
        )
    )
);
```